# angularjs how to push a value to specific position of array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, array-splice

I have a select dropdown which gets value from an array. I want to push a value to the first position of the array if the condition is true.

```
<select name="child_age">
    <option ng-repeat="child_age in age">{{child_age.childCount}}</option>
</select>
```

Child age Array
$scope.age = [{childCount:'1 Yr'},{childCount:'2 Yrs'}];

I want to push following Value to the first position.
    $scope.age.push({
    childCount: 'Child 1 Age'
    })

But it has been added to the last position.

Also I tried following code as well

```
$scope.age.splice(0,0,"Child 1 Age")
```

It shows the position. But not displaying the value

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to push wrong format of the data. It should be inserted as

```
$scope.age.splice(0,0,{childCount:"Child 1 Age"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.push` use [`.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

I would also suggest using [`ng-options`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) instead of doing the `ng-repeat` yourself, but that shouldn't make a functional difference in this case.